# SQL stored precedure 2 insertstatements with 1 select needed for one insert

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I got a website with a database running on `MySQL Community Server (GPL) version 5.5.37`

And I want to write a stored precedure to insert an image in table 1 then select the id from that last post to insert that id in table 2.

I started to google and ended up with this:

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewMedia( 
    IN insertLocatie varchar(255),
    IN insertNaam varchar(150), 
    IN insertOmschrijving longtext, 
    IN insertCategorieID  int
)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO MediaDB (idMediaDB, Locatie, Naam, Omschrijving) VALUES (NULL, insertLocatie, insertNaam, insertOmschrijving);

SELECT MAX(idMediaDB) AS Nieuwste FROM MediaDB;

INSERT INTO MediaLink (idMediaLink, OverMijShoots_idOverMijShoots, MediaDB_idMediaDB) VALUES (NULL, insertCategorieID, Nieuwste);

END
```

---

I know this is a wrong code but I can't find a good awnser on what I need.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewMedia(
    IN insertLocatie varchar(255),
    IN insertNaam varchar(150),
    IN insertOmschrijving longtext,
    IN insertCategorieID int
)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MediaDB(idMediaDB, Locatie, Naam, Omschrijving)
        VALUES (NULL, insertLocatie, insertNaam, insertOmschrijving);

     INSERT INTO MediaLink (idMediaLink, OverMijShoots_idOverMijShoots, MediaDB_idMediaDB)
        VALUES (NULL, insertCategorieID, LAST_INSERT_ID());

END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks I was searching and searching and I couldn't find a good awnser to what I needed/wanted to do :-)